# Change Gradient Background of UIView Through Sublayer

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, cagradientlayer

I've got this function defined in an extension of `UIView` which I use to set the gradient background on a `UIView`:

```
func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor, withCornerRadius : CGFloat){
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorBottom.cgColor, colorTop.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = withCornerRadius
    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```

It is used as follows:

```
view.setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor.blue, colorBottom: UIColor.red, withCornerRadius: 10)
```

The problem is, if I have already called this function once on a view, the second time I call it, it does not do anything. I suspect this is caused by the `subLayer` persisting from the previous insertion.

I've tried adding:

```
if layer.sublayers?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
    layer.sublayers?.remove(at: 0)
}
```

to the top of that function, but that causes by code to crash with a `BAD_INSTRUCTION` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Gradient layer and can remove from view anywhere you want to ... Not just by adding it again you remove it..

```
if let gradientLayer = (yourView.layer.sublayers?.compactMap { $0 as? CAGradientLayer })?.first {

    print("gradientLayer is presnet")
       gradientLayer.removeFromSuperlayer() 

} else {

    print("its not added on layer yet")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to check to see if the layer's sublayer is a gradient layer. This isn't perfectly safe because if you happen to have another gradient layer at index 0 of the sublayers, it will change the incorrect sublayer.

```
func setGradientBackground(colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor, withCornerRadius cornerRadius: CGFloat) {
  let gradientLayer = layer.sublayers?.first as? CAGradientLayer ?? CAGradientLayer()
  // The rest of your existing layer customization code here

  guard gradientLayer.superlayer != self else {
    return
  }
  layer.sublayers?.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}
```